# Pyinstaller with Kivy crashes when using window only mode

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Kivy app that I am trying to package with Pyinstaller.
I am able to package the app and run the executable.
However if I disable the console it errors out.

I have removed all print statements from the code.
I think it has something to do with the Kivy logging output to the console.
I have tried the following code and it seems to disable the logging however it does not fix my issue.

```
Logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
Config.set('kivy', 'log_enable', '0')
Config.write()
```

How do I disable the Kivy logging or stop the Pyinstaller executable from requiring it?

Thanks,

This is the error I get when running the exe

```
Failed to excute script __main__
```

.spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
import os

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['__main__.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\User_Control'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='User_Control',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

Comment: Do you include a `console=False,` in your `exe` section of your `.spec` file? Or include a `--noconsole` option to `Pyinstaller`?

Comment: Yes if I set console=False then I get an error. If I set console=True it works just fine.

Comment: Is there an actual error message that you can share with us?

Comment: I added the error message to the question and mt current .spec file.

Comment: This may be just a SWAG, but double underlines can cause problems inside Python scripts. I have never heard of double underlines causing problems in file names. But I would try compiling and running  after copying your `__main__.py` to `main.py`, copying `__main__.spec` to `main.spec` and making the appropriate changes in the spec file.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but I believe I found the answer to my problem.
In the app I am using QWINSTA to pull a list of users currently logged onto a server.
I rebuilt the app with WX as a GUI and if I run pyinstaller without the console the app launches but can't pull any data.

I believe that this line of code is the problem since for some reason with the console enabled it can't run.

```
subprocess.check_output("QWINSTA /server:{}".format(server), shell=False)
```